# Is it safe to make symbolic links in /root to config files in a a users home directory?

Tags: root, symlink, home

Does symlinking from /root to a configuration file in a users home directory bad practice security-wise?

For example I currently have /root/.vimrc symlinked to ~/.vimrc

Is it a viable attack to make changes to the file in the users home directory to execute commands when the same config is used by the root user?

Comment: Also if you have multiple admins, it might annoy them to run across your personal config up in `/root` (unless you can get them to agree on the One True Config), or be problematic if the user homedir gets user-encryption, etc.

Comment: `vim` can run external commands (any command, including `rm`, `chown`, `chmod` etc), so the user who owns the symlinked `~/.vimrc` can cause root to execute whatever they like whenever root runs `vim` (as can anyone else who has write access to that .vimrc or to the user's home directory). they can trivially get a root shell (e.g. by getting root to make a setuid root copy of `/bin/bash`).

Answer (score 3):

If the software root is using can be configured to do "evil" stuff (or to display information in some unexpected way so that the root user does "evil" stuff out of not-knowing or false knowledge) by the config file, then that is a viable attack.

In general, you weaken security, if access rights to edit `~/<configfile>` can be more easily gained for that user than for root, and also if that user uses the system in a "normal" way which gives the chance that he uses some bad software which could edit the config file.

So, try to avoid that if you are concerned about security.